# Zend_Validate_Regex, cannot set custom  error message

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am having some annoying trouble setting a custom error message for a Zend_Validate_Regex.

I know I am getting lost in the syntax so any help would be appreciated my element declaration :

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'label' => 'E-Mail',
    'title' => 'email..',
    'required' => true,           
    'validators' => array(
        array('Regex',
            true,
            array('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i'),
            'messages' => array(Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH,
                'my not match message',
                Zend_Validate_Regex::INVALID  => 'my invalid message',
                Zend_Validate_Regex::ERROROUS => 'my errorous message',
            )
        )
    )
));
```

I have also tried:

```
'messages'=>array(
    'regexNotMatch'=>'Your own custom error message'
)
```

but always I get the default error message.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this OO way to create forms. Custom messages work fine like this:

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$regex = new Zend_Validate_Regex('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i');
$regex->setMessages(array(
    Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH => 'my not match message',
    Zend_Validate_Regex::INVALID   => 'my invalid message',
    Zend_Validate_Regex::ERROROUS  => 'my errorous message'
));
$el = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
$el->setLabel('E-Mail')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addValidator($regex);
$form->addElement($el);
```

**NOTE**: why are you using Regex validator instead of EmailAddress?

Comment: it still returns the default message

Comment: we have to compare different values in the sameway elsewhere

Comment: e.g. so their is no reason we are not using EmailAddress but elsewhere we regex validate other stuff and face the same problem/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'label' => 'E-Mail',
    'title' => 'email..',
    'required' => true,           
    'validators' => array(
        array('Regex',
            true,
            array(
                '/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i',
                'messages' => array(
                    Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH => 'my not match message',
                    Zend_Validate_Regex::INVALID  => 'my invalid message',
                    Zend_Validate_Regex::ERROROUS => 'my errorous message',
            )
        )
    )
));
```